# Android searchview on fragment

Tags: search, navigation, android-arrayadapter, searchview, drawer

I am developing an android app, which contains a Navigation Drawer Activity. This in turn contains two tabs "Alabanzas" and "Tema", both are accessed from the side menu.
The "Alabanzas" tab is a Fragment that contains a custom ArrayAdapter that contains a ListView.
In the ActionBar place a SearchView element for the searches within the ListView of "Alabanzas", however I can not link the search with the elements of the ListView
My Classes are the Following ...

Class MainActivity with Navigation Drawer
Error in the method onQueryTextChange of the method onCreateOptionsMenu generates the `miadaptador.getFilter().Filter(s);` because that adapter is different from the one installed in the Adapter class that has the search method

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.example.misael.corolldm.Fragmentos.Alabanza;
import com.example.misael.corolldm.Fragmentos.Temas;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        CargarFragmento(new Alabanza());
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search,menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
        SearchView searchView= (SearchView)item.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            //    miadaptador.getFilter().filter(s);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            CargarFragmento(new Alabanza());
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
           CargarFragmento(new Temas());
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    private void CargarFragmento(Fragment fragmento){
        FragmentManager Manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedorFragmento, fragmento).commit();

    }
}
```

Xml Archive activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Class Adaptador

public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    Context contexto;

```
ArrayList<Datos> ListaObjetos;
ArrayList<Datos> mStringFilterList;

ValueFilter valueFilter;

public Adaptador(Context contexto, ArrayList<Datos> listaObjetos) {
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.ListaObjetos = listaObjetos;
    mStringFilterList=listaObjetos;
}

/*
Retorna cantidad de elementos de la vista
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.ListaObjetos.size();
}

/*
    Retorna objeto puntual de la posicion que indico
     */
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return this.ListaObjetos.get(i);
}

/*
Retorna Id del objeto puntual de la posicion que indico
 */
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return this.ListaObjetos.get(i).getId();
}

/*
Se ejecuta en cada secuencia de cada hito de la listview
 */
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View vista = view;

    //Inyectamos el layout definido dentro de la vista del ListView
    LayoutInflater inflate = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
    vista = inflate.inflate(R.layout.itemlistview, null);

    //Referenciamos el titulo
    TextView titulo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tw_titulo);
    titulo.setText(ListaObjetos.get(i).getTitulo().toString());
    return vista;
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Datos> filterList = new ArrayList<Datos>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getTitulo().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                    Datos data = new Datos(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                            .getId(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                            .getTitulo());

                    filterList.add(data);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        } else {
            results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
            results.values = mStringFilterList;
        }
        return results;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        ListaObjetos = (ArrayList<Datos>) filterResults.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

Class Alabanza

public class Alabanza extends Fragment {

```
ListView listaDatos;
ArrayList<Datos> Lista= new ArrayList<>();

Adaptador miadaptador;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alabanza, container, false);

    listaDatos = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lstDatos);

    Lista.add(new Datos(1,"A la Diestra de Dios"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(2,"A solas al Huerto"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(3,"A ti Señor"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(4,"A veces me pregunto"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(5,"Al divino Salvador"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(6,"Al Mundo Paz"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(7,"Alabado el gran manantial"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(8,"Alabanzas a Dios dad"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(9,"Aleluya Amen"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(10,"Aleluya oh Creador"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(11,"Angeles cantando estan"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(12,"Apocalipsis 14_6"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(13,"Bendito Amor"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(14,"Blancos Vestidos"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(15,"Cantad a Jehova"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(16,"Canten a Cristo Rey"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(17,"Cerca de ti señor"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(18,"Contigo estoy tan Feliz"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(19,"Cuan Amables son tus Moradas"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(20,"Cuando el Señor manifesto"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(21,"Cuarenta Años de amor"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(22,"Del Celeste Pais"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(23,"Don Inefable"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(24,"Dulce Oracion"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(25,"El Amigo del Angel"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(26,"El Apóstol de la Consolación"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(27,"El Evangelio de Cristo"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(28,"El Lema de la Iglesia"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(29,"El Manto de la Eleccion"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(30,"El mas bello amor"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(31,"El Nuevo Israel"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(32,"El Replicar del Campanal"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(33,"El Resplandor de tu nacimiento"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(33,"El vino a mi corazon"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(34,"Elección de Dios"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(35,"En la Judea"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(36,"En las mañanas de bendicion"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(37,"Engrandecido sea Dios"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(38,"Eres el Angel"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(39,"Estoy resuelto"));



    miadaptador = new Adaptador(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Lista);
    listaDatos.setAdapter(miadaptador);

    //Agregamos escuchador
    listaDatos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Datos obj=(Datos) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

            //Creamos el paso hacia la nueva activity
            Intent paso=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), DetalleActivity.class);
            paso.putExtra("objeto", (Serializable) obj); // Serializamos el traspaso del objeto
            //Realiza el traspaso a la otra activity
            startActivity(paso);

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Xml Archive menu_search

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menuSearch"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"

        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

If anyone could help me perform searches in the listView of the fragment "Alabanzas", any idea will be very well received
Thank you